# Why two .war files build with maven from the same project are diffrent?

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I did like below - checkout **the same project** twice and build war twice:

```
git clone repo ~/p1
git clone repo ~/p2

cd ~/p1 && mvn clean package
cd ~/p2 && mvn clean package

diff ~/p1/target/app.war ~/p2/target/app.war
Files /home/marioosh/p1/target/app.war and /home/marioosh/p2/target/app.war differ
```

Why these files are different?

Comment: Is it possible to make a diff on a folder basis, down to all files recursively? If yes, then you extract the contents to two separate folders and see which file(s) cause the difference and share it with us :)

Answer (score 1):

[melihcelik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644766/melihcelik), Thanks for suggestion. I have compared `target` directories and found the difference. During build Maven geneate in `/META-INF/maven/` directory `pom.properties` files that differ (have different dates)

```
#Generated by Maven
#Thu Jan 12 13:26:37 CET 2012
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
groupId=net.marioosh.test
artifactId=app
```